# profile.ps1 how import scripts and functions

Tags: powershell

I have some functions and scripts what I make myself. The issue is that I am not sure where that save and how to load.

On local profile I have this:
C:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

With this:

```
Import-Module c:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Get-serialnumber.ps1 -Force
Import-Module c:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Invoke-AutoIPAssigning.ps1 -Force
Import-Module C:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Reset-Password.ps1 -Force
Import-Module C:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Send-Email.ps1 -Force
```

In these files, I have functions/scripts. This is a good practice or maybe I should in another way import it? Use ForEach to load all files in this location? 
If one function will use another (example always after reset password I want to send e-mail) how I should import it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've never seen `Import-Module` used to import the definitions from a script, I don't even know if this would work. Usually one would dot-source `.` library scripts from their `$profile` like so:

Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1

```
. c:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Get-serialnumber.ps1
. c:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Invoke-AutoIPAssigning.ps1
. C:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Reset-Password.ps1
. C:\Users\Plazma\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Send-Email.ps1
```

Dot sourcing executes a script in the context of the calling session, so anything defined at the script scope, such as functions or variables, become available in the parent session.

---

However, if you have a LOT of these scripts you're lugging around a network, the best solution would be to write these into (one or more) modules as modules are more portable, and you [can host your own NuGet feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) if you don't want to upload to the public [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/).